# How to run installed Ubuntu on windows 7?

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside windows 7. But I need to know is there any way to run my installed Ubuntu using some Virtual Machines on windows 7? Mention that the Ubuntu is installed on my laptop boot.

Answer (score 1):

It is **not possible** to run installed ubuntu alongside windows on virtual machine running in windows 7.

You can run an ubuntu.iso file in virtual machine on windows.But it is not possible to run installed ubuntu(*already installed in the hard-disk*) on a virtual machine in windows.